# How to deploy a Zend Framework app using the 'public' directory on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku

Basically for a Facebook tab I have a PHP app and want Heroku to use the 'public' folder as the web server's root folder instead of pointing to the very root of the app files. Any help would be awesome as it seems Heroku doesn't have a ton of documentation around it's config options. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku has PHP support. Check [this](http://blog.pajap.com/?p=102) article on how to run php frameworks on heroku. It explains Symfony2 integration but to apply that in Zend is easy